# How to make TouchableOpacity button to prevent multiple clicks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I have `TouchableOpacity` with event that I don't want to execute twice.
I tried to put in it's `onPress` event `bool` in state but this doesn't work as setting state is async and I can press button multiple times fast.
I also tried to set timer but this also doesn't work for me.
Is there any other way to prevent multiple press on button (some other similar component etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to `setState` to store values which do not reflect as UI changes.

You could directly have a `this.flag` instead of `this.state.flag` inside your React Class which you set on TouchableOpacity click.  So, you can set `this.flag` without it being asynchronous operation involving a render cycle. It'll just be a flag which your component holds.

See example below:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = { ... }; // this does not need to store our flag
   this.touchableInactive = false; // this is not state variable. hence sync
  }

  onButtonClick () {
    if (!this.touchableInactive) {
      this.touchableInactive = true;
      // do stuff
    }
  }

      // similarly reset this.touchableInactive to false somewhere else
}
```